# why my index.html configured by Echarts with Electron not worked?

Tags: electron, echarts

Now my project folder named as "App" has four modules: "electron-packager", "electron", "echarts","echarts-gl".
now I command "npm start" to run the echarts demo, but index.html has not shown as expected.
**I guess some function has not worked,  such as "echarts.init" and "myChart.setOption"**, since the prompt is "any" by VSCode . **Or should be something wrong with the relationship between these modules?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ECharts</title>
    <!-- import echarts.js -->
    <script src="echarts.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
    <!-- prepare a Dom for echarts -->
    <div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // prepare a dom for echarts
        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

        // configure option
        var option = {
            title: {
                text: 'ECharts demo'
            },
            tooltip: {},
            legend: {
                data:['a']
            },
            xAxis: {
                data: ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
            },
            yAxis: {},
            series: [{
                name: 'a',
                type: 'bar',
                data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20]
            }]
        };

        // use option
        myChart.setOption(option);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the window is empty, displaying like this,
[image]

Comment: What do you see in the [debug console](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-debugging#application-debugging)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a security issue, try to add into `</head>`:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

Comment: I have solved it. I use the wrong script , the script should be echarts.min.js not echarts.js